# i want to selected textarea  text like bold italic underline using java script in asp mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i want to selected text into text area like bold italic underlineand spell check  using java script or jquery  plz help me or give me a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

there are many available like

1. http://ckeditor.com/ the best one
2. http://www.openwebware.com/
3. http://www.htmlarea.com/
4. http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

they are easily integrate able and provide tons and tons of functionality, i would rather say almost MS word for the web